# Web Search using C# Program

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I am trying to do a web search from within a C# app. I am currently using this code that gets an error.

```
WebRequest http = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse(); //error occurs here
```

I keep getting "The remote name could not be resolved: 'search.yahooapis.com'".

Here is the code for the url parameter:

```
 StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.Append("http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?");
        url.Append("appid=YahooDemo&results=100&query=");
        url.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(searchFor));
```

The problem, I think, is that I need an API key from Yahoo in place of 'YahooDemo' in the above code. I went to http://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects and got an application ID but when I enter it it still does not work? I think the problem is I did not know what to put in the Yahoo project for Application URL and Callback Domain - I don't really know what this even means? I am happy to use other providers such as Google or Bing if this makes it easier. But I am new to C# so really need detailed but simple explanations to understand what I need to do. I am a bit lost. In the end I basically just want to do a web search from my C# program to look for key words, so if their is an easier way to do this I am all for it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check with Simple Url with out query params .. and see if that is successful .. then query string formation could be issue

Comment: it works with a simple URL. Have checked this.

Comment: By simple URL that works, do you mean `search.yahooapis.com`? Because that error looks very much like a simple DNS lookup failure to me.

Comment: Also please try putting @ before your string like url.Append(@"http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?")

Comment: @kishoreVM - you don't have to. He's using characters that needn't be escaped in the url.

Comment: Agree with @Nenotlep. An appId error would probably throw a different error, such as unauthenticated request.

Comment: I have put in "url.Append("http://search.yahooapis.com");" into the  code and it comes back with the same error. But works if I use somethign completely different like "http://google.com". I also tried it in the browser and it did not work. So any clues as to what I can do about this? Are there any easier or alternative solutions to doing a web search - like google or bing? Preferably without an appID? Thanks for your help by the way guys.